# Form content as PostGre query parameter

Tags: php, postgresql

So, I'm pretty new to web. I'm always fiddling with HTML and SQL, but recently I started working on a project. This project is basically creating a database with all employees contact data (name, email, phone number, etc) and show it on web. Database is set, web page is connecting normally to DB (I can call PHP and send a query, results are shown perfectly). BUT I don't know how to use a `<form>` content (text written by user) as a Query Parameter. I want to send the parameter when Enter or the 'busca' button are pressed.
Here is the form

```
<form id="searchbox" >
    <label for="sectname">
    </label>
    <input id="sectname" name="sectname" type="search"      placeholder="Busca" list="setor" class="searchbox"/>
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <input id="submit" type="button" class="button" value="BUSCA"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is the PHP with query

```
$host        = "host=localhost";
$port        = "port=5432";
$dbname      = "dbname=Cards";
$creds = "user=postgres password=12345678";

$db = pg_connect( "$host $port $dbname $creds"  );
if(!$db){
  echo nl2br ("Unable to open database\n");
} 

$sql =<<<EOF
  SELECT * from Cards where nome='Diego Teste';
EOF;

$ret = pg_query($db, $sql);
if(!$ret){
  echo pg_last_error($db);
  exit;
} 
while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($ret)){
   echo "<div>";
  echo "<img src='".$row['pic']."'class='cardcontent2'/>";
   echo "<div class='carddata'>";
  echo nl2br ("\nNome: ".$row['nome'] . "\n");
  echo nl2br ("Email: ".$row['email'] . "\n");
  echo nl2br ("Ramal: ".$row['ramal'] . "\n");
  echo nl2br ("Número: ".$row['numero'] . "\n");
  echo nl2br ("Setor: ".$row['setor'] . "\n\n");
  echo "</div>";
  echo "</div>";
}

pg_close($db);
```

I want 'nome="Diego Teste"' to be 'nome= %var%' and the %var% value should be text written by user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use prepared statements: ([ref](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php))

```
$basequery =<<<EOF
    SELECT * from Cards where nome = $1;
EOF;

pg_prepare($db, "my_query", $basequery);
$results = pg_execute($db, "my_query", array($_GET["nome"]));

...
```

Prepared statements take care of escaping any values you will pass to SQL, so you do not have to do it yourself. It protects you from SQL injection; some people will fill form fields with malicious content that can trip up your SQL statement if you just put the field's text in-place.

My PHP might be a bit rusty, so please forgive me if I made minor mistakes.

Comment: Since you are new to web, if PHP is not a requirement, I would suggest looking into Python or Ruby; these languages tend to be more popular and appeal to a larger audience.

Comment: I will look into Python and Ruby! I thought that PHP had have a larger user base so, when help is needed it would be easier to find.

Comment: I do not have lots of references to back this claim. It depends a lot on your entourage: in the corporate world, .NET, Java and to an extent PHP are very popular, but in the start-up and open source worlds, Python and Ruby are king. And paradoxically, some very big companies use Python, Ruby and JavaScript (node.js). If JavaScript is your cup of tea, you might want to give node.js a go.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, by the way! Make sure you have [read the rules](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and do not forget to upvote good answers and accept the one that helped you the most!

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! Well, since I'm really curious, I will eventually study and develop something basic with both of them! As you about your answer: It worked! Now I just need to work on the Pattern Matching.